# Combining several targeted value's / variable in one piece

Tags: php

We currently use the following piece of PHP code to target (change) several variables. Though this works, is there some way to shorten it? I am guessing there is a shorter way, however we don't have any PHP knowledge.

```
            if($form_id == 10767){
            if($data['element_id'] == 13){
                if(empty($data['value'])){
                    $data['value'] .= '';
                }else{
                    $data['value'] = '<p style="font-size:13px;">'.$data['value'].'</p>';
                }
            }
        }

        if($form_id == 10767){
            if($data['element_id'] == 14){
                if(empty($data['value'])){
                    $data['value'] .= '';
                }else{
                    $data['value'] = '<p style="font-size:13px;">'.$data['value'].'</p>';
                }
            }
        }

        if($form_id == 10767){
            if($data['element_id'] == 16){
                if(empty($data['value'])){
                    $data['value'] .= '';
                }else{
                    $data['value'] = '<p style="font-size:13px;">'.$data['value'].'</p>';
                }
            }
        }

        if($form_id == 10767){
            if($data['element_id'] == 17){
                if(empty($data['value'])){
                    $data['value'] .= '';
                }else{
                    $data['value'] = '<p style="font-size:13px;">'.$data['value'].'</p>';
                }
            }
        }
```

I think it's possible to combine those element_id's into one single line, instead of targeting them seperately, right?

Something like this:

```
if($data['element_id'] == 13,14,16,17)
```

I tried a few things myself, but every time I get an error or break things.

Thank you kindly in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load your targets into an array and then us `in_array(needle, haystack)` it can be easily reduced.

With a ternary operator instead of an IF it can be even more reduced.

```
$target_ids = array(13,14,16,17);
if($form_id == 10767){
    if( in_array($data['element_id'], $target_ids)) {
        $data['value'] = empty($data['value']) ? '' : '<p style="font-size:13px;">'.$data['value'].'</p>';

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. You win. `in_array()` was a nicer touch (more readable) than my example. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're currently use the same if-statements several times, which isn't needed:
Then you should look into the [documentation about "if"](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) and about [Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) and you will find how to write "or":

```
if($form_id == 10767){
    if($data['element_id'] == 13 || $data['element_id'] == 14 || ...etc... ){
        if(!empty($data['value'])){
            $data['value'] = '<p style="font-size:13px;">'.$data['value'].'</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

I also removed `$data['value'] .= '';` on empty, since it doesn't do anything. (notice the `!` before `empty()` which means that it validates if the value is *not* empty.)

Comment: Ah now I understand what I did wrong...!

I did actually use || and the number, but I didn't add the "$data['element_id'] =="-string.

Thank you for explaining.